# How can I reduce metagaming?

Tags: metagaming

I have DM'd a couple of times and have been a long standing D&D/Pathfinder player. The one thing I see a lot in the games that I've played is metagaming.

For example, everyone rolls a Spot check. Only one person notices the creature, but then everyone starts to act cautiously, even if they don't mean to. I have tried to write down notes and handing it to one person but that slows the game down.

I'm about to start a new campaign where I am the DM, and I was wondering how to solve or at least make this easier.

Comment: Possibly already answered in [How do you discourage "player knowledge" as a GM?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/7921) Toshiro, can you take a look at that question and see if it solves your problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it did! I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate so that they're officially linked together as being “the same problem”. (If there's any aspect of your problem not solved by the previous question though, just edit this question post to highlight what's different that you still need help with, and it can be unmarked as a duplicate.) Cheers!