# Do reactions that trigger on saving throws give knowledge of saving throws that would otherwise be secret?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, saving-throw, reactions, metagaming

#### Preliminaries.

Some reactions have triggers which are tangible events in the fiction of the game. For example, *feather fall*'s casting time is:

> 1 reaction, which you take when you or a creature within 60 feet of you falls.

This is something tangible within the fiction: *feather fall's trigger is something perceived and understood by both the player out of game and the character in game.*

On the other hand, some reactions have triggers which are intangible within the fiction of the game: they are perceived only by the player out of game, and do not actually reflect anything about the character's knowledge in game. For example, the Artificer's Flash of Genius ability says:

> When you or another creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an ability check or a saving throw, you can use your reaction to add your Intelligence modifier to the roll.

Another example is the Oath of the Watchers Paladin's Vigilant Rebuke ability:

> You’ve learned how to chastise anyone who dares wield beguilements against you and your wards. Whenever you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you succeeds on an Intelligence, a Wisdom, or a Charisma saving throw, you can use your reaction to deal 2d8 + your Charisma modifier force damage to the creature that forced the saving throw.

Both of these abilities allow the character to take a reaction in response to another character making a saving throw.

*But passing, failing, or even attempting a saving throw are not something characters know about.* Characters don't even know what saving throws are. This is clear from the spellcasting rules in the *Player's Handbook*:

> Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature might not know it was targeted by a spell at all. An effect like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more subtle effect, such as an attempt to read a creature's thoughts, typically goes unnoticed, unless a spell says otherwise.

These two questions go into more depth about detecting saving throws:

- [In 5e, are saving throw results detected by the opposing party?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61792/62294)
- [Do characters know if someone else, who they can see, has failed a saving throw?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121605/62294)

#### The Scenario.

Suppose the evil Archmage casts *scrying* on one of our party members, in an attempt to secretly spy on them. *Scrying* calls for a wisdom saving throw. *The party (in the fiction) would normally have no idea this was going on, no idea someone was making a saving throw, and no idea if that saving throw succeeded or failed* (see rule about perceptible spell effects quoted above).

But what if we have an Artificer or Watchers Paladin around?

*Rules as written* the artificer or paladin would be able to use their respective reactions in response to the saving throw for the Archmage's *scrying*.

**Do the artificer and paladin characters know in game that they used their abilities in response to the saving throw against the *scrying* spell?**

Obviously, they don't know what a saving throw is, and won't know that it is a *scrying* spell at work. But do they know that *something* is afoot and that they used their ability?

I am asking this from the perspective as a DM trying to help my players manage player meta-knowledge as they make decisions in character.

Comment: When you say 'characters don't know...', you should be aware that that's very much a matter of playstyle and that, as far as these rules are concerned, it's expected that characters *do* know.  It's obviously fine to decide that for your game characters *don't* know, but it shouldn't be surprising that a ruling like that (just like the converse) requires some adjustment to rules that expect the opposite.

Comment: @user66659 "Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature might not know it was targeted by a spell at all. An effect like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more subtle effect, such as an attempt to read a creature's thoughts, typically goes unnoticed, unless a spell says otherwise." -PHB. The rules are quite clear that you would not know you were targetted by a *scrying* spell.

Comment: Right, but different parts of the rules have contradictory expectations.

Comment: @user66659 Im not sure what that means.

Comment: @user66659 I think that's exactly the question here? These mechanics don't imply that _characters_ know anything in particular--your Paladin doesn't need to know that someone just attempted a Wisdom saving throw and he used his reaction to deal force damage. "Saving throw", "reaction", and "force damage" are all gameplay abstractions. The question is whether he needs to know that _anything_ is happening. _You_ have a choice about whether to activate Vigilant Rebuke, but are you limited by in-character knowledge, or is that a metagame decision?

Comment: The usual answer to this is "rulings > rules" so what's the problem at the table to solve?  Are you asking this question as a DM or as a player?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Asking as a DM helping players manage meta knowledge as they make decisions.

Comment: FWIW: worth including in the question for context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How it reads, Rules-As-Written

Nothing in the [rules for reactions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Reactions) indicates that the trigger must be perceptible:

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a special action called a reaction. A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can occur on your turn or on someone else's. The opportunity attack, described later in this section, is the most common type of reaction.

In fact, Flash of Genius and Vigilant Rebuke can both trigger on saving throws, which are inherently not perceptible. The only perception requirement for both abilities is that you can see the creature that is making the saving throw (or ability check).

Both abilities are active abilities that the *characters* choose to use, not just the player on a meta level (emphasis mine):

> Starting at 7th level, you gain the ability to **come up with solutions under pressure**. When you or another creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an ability check or a saving throw, you can use your reaction to add your Intelligence modifier to the roll.

> You’ve learned how to **chastise anyone who dares wield beguilements against you and your wards**. Whenever you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you succeeds on an Intelligence, a Wisdom, or a Charisma saving throw, you can use your reaction to deal 2d8 + your Charisma modifier force damage to the creature that forced the saving throw.

So, as written, **there is no restriction against using the abilities in this case**, and because of the active nature of the abilities, **the *character* would know they used their ability** (i.e. not just player meta-knowledge) even if it is unclear what it was used for.

---

### How I would rule it

The above is the rules as I see them, but to me it just seems a little ridiculous for cases where the character would have no clue something was going on, such as the example with the *scrying* in the question.

Because the abilities referenced are both used actively, the character (not just the player) must choose when to use it. If the event causing a saving throw has no way to be known to the character, they have no information to go off of in order to choose to use the ability at that time.

So, I would personally rule that unless the character has reasonable knowledge that the saving throw happened (or in-game context that *something is wrong*, a perceptible spell being cast, trap triggered, etc.), they would have no way to know to use their ability in that instance. RAW successfully saved spells do not have perceptible effects unless specified in the spell's description, so this would obviously be up to the DM's discretion to determine when something is perceptible/noticeable to the character, but it seems like a more logical approach to me.

Comment: I'm gonna pull this [to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116672/discussion-between-revenantbacon-and-smbailey) because I have a feeling it could get quite wordy

Answer (score 13):

### Yes...

#### but this knowledge can be given to players, rather than characters

As you correctly point out, RAW a *character* does not know that they have been targeted by a *scrying* spell.  But if that character has an ability that allows them to react to just such a targeting, or allows them to react to something that forces a saving throw they don't know about, then there is just the difficulty or contradiction you describe.

As a DM in this situation, you have a few choices:

1. **You can choose to *not* describe the triggering event and thus keep the character from using their ability.**  While this does adhere to rules as written, you are basically deciding a rules contradiction in favor of the NPC and *against* the character.

   Of course, it goes both ways, and the characters can do this in their own *scrying*.  But given that the features you mention are class-specific, and the players likely chose their class with certain features in mind, it would not be surprising if some of the players feel that you are unfairly "nerfing their character", since it will limit them *every time* their class could have used that ability and limit the NPCs only in the rare case that you have made the NPC have a class with one of these abilities.
2. **You can assume that the character feels something on the subconscious level, and then decides to use their ability without being aware of it – no character knowledge of the trigger is needed.**  While this at least allows the character to use their ability, it robs the *player* of the agency in making the decision of *when* to use it.

   > At 15th level, you've learned how to magically chastise anyone who dares cast unwanted spells at you and your wards. Whenever you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you succeeds on a saving throw against a spell, you can use your reaction to deal 2d8 + your Charisma modifier force damage to the spellcaster.

   For the Watcher Oath Paladins, since there is no per-day or per-rest limit to the use of this ability, one way out of requiring character knowledge is just to say, "Your paladin does this instinctively.  It is a reaction, after all, and most reactions happen faster than thought.  We can assume that *any time* something forces a save on you or your allies, you use this ability if you can, even if you don't realize that you used it."  That may work narratively to spare you having the character actually know about the saving throw.  But even if you do this, each PC gets only one reaction per round.  Action economy means that sometimes there would be a choice between using this ability or taking another reaction.  Do they punish a minion for casting a spell on an ally, **or** take an opportunity attack on the Big Bad?  For Watcher Oath Paladins in particular, by 15th level they have access to *counterspell*.  When the Paladin wants to counter an enemy caster clearly casting, do you really want to tell them them that 'actually, you can't because you used your reaction earlier in the round when a spell was cast on your ally, you just didn't notice it.'

   > When you or another creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an ability check or a saving throw, you can use your reaction to add your Intelligence modifier to the roll.
   > You can use this feature a number of times equal to your Intelligence modifier (minimum of once). You regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

   For an Artificer the stakes are even higher.  Not only does the player have to consider the opportunity cost of making a reaction within the action economy, but they also have to decide whether or not to spend a resource that is limited to a few uses per long rest.  If you rob them of that decision by having it happen whenever it can, they will likely feel cheated.  An ability like this is typically saved for "important" rolls – but by having it happen at any time it is possible, you will likely exhaust it long before the player would have used it if they had been the one deciding.
3. **You can tell the *player* as much as you like about what is happening, but expect them to compartmentalize that knowledge from the character.** This could be as subtle as "Your subconscious mind detects the presence of malign forces of which you are not consciously aware – do you have an intuitive response to protect yourself and your allies?"  It might be as explicit as "Okay, someone is trying a divination spell that permits a save on someone in the party – does the paladin or artificer want to do anything about it?" and then you *trust* that the characters don't start trying to actively find magic that blocks divination in the campaign just because of what you told the players.

You know your table and you know how you want to run your game, but obviously I think option #3 is the way to go.  Removing the decision from a player because their character would not realize a save was being made says you can't trust your players with metagame knowledge.  If you want to tell your players that you to trust them to keep their end of the social contract, you can say "I'm going to give you just enough information so that you can make your decision fairly, but in return you have to have your character act as if they don't know what save was made, at least within the boundaries of allowable metagaming at our table."

I believe the DM should provide the player with just enough information to make reasonable decisions, even if that player then has to pretend that their character didn't know exactly what was happening.  Not allowing players access to the information they need to use their abilities robs them of agency.  Ultimately it is the *players* who are making the decisions, not their characters.

### Decisions are made by players, not characters

Players can try to think in terms of "how would my character react based on just what *they* know?", and this can add depth to their role-playing, but ultimately it is still the players making the decisions, and some degree of metagaming is inevitable.

Different tables have different styles of play, from min-maxers playing a strategy game with the *Monster Manual* open at the table, to story-tellers where the DM rolls *all* the dice, including for players, in secret so that players don't know how well they did beyond the narrative.  The amount of "pretending to not know" varies between groups, but even at tables that greatly restrict player knowledge, some metagaming is inevitable.  ([This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/how-to-prevent-metagaming-induced-by-trying-to-not-metagame) has some interesting discussion of a kind of reactionary metagaming, where the players are trying so hard to show that their characters don't know some things that their behaviors become nonsensical within the context of the game world.)

For those who enjoy a style of play that focuses on in-character knowledge and motivation there assistance built into the game.  For example, spells and abilities are often described with in-character "fluff" first and game "crunch" after.  Consider the description of the bard's Cutting Words feature:

> you learn how to use your wit to distract, confuse, and otherwise sap the confidence and competence of others.

(**versus**)

> When a creature that you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a damage roll, you can use your reaction to expend one of your uses of Bardic Inspiration, rolling a Bardic Inspiration die and subtracting the number rolled from the creature’s roll.

The second part is what the *player* knows, the first part is what the player pretends the *character* knows.  It is not what the character actually knows, though, because **the character doesn't actually know anything.  The character is a fiction.**  The player *pretends* the character knows or does not know things in order to achieve a certain style of play.

Consider the OP question's statement that "Characters don't even know what saving throws are."  One of my players is a Warlock who has the Dark One's Own Luck Patron feature and who chose the *Mind Sliver* spell.

> Starting at 6th level, you can call on your patron to alter fate in your favor. When you make an ability check or a saving throw, you can use this feature to add a d10 to your roll.

When my player wants to use this to turn a failed save into a success, do I inform them that their character doesn't know that saving throws exist, so they can't call on their patron for anything but skill checks?  Do I say that they are not permitted to use one of the key mechanics of their patron choice?

With the limited number of spells available to Warlocks, how should my player decide on choosing *Mind Sliver* compared to other options *without admitting character knowledge of saving throws*?

> You drive a disorienting spike of psychic energy into the mind of one creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on an Intelligence saving throw or take 1d6 psychic damage and subtract 1d4 from the next saving throw it makes before the end of your next turn.

I can permit my player to say "Spells that debuff saves are great, I'll take it!"  Or I can remind them that their character doesn't know what a saving throw is, so they have to make their spell selection based on "The first part of the spell damages the psyche of my opponent and the second... makes them... unlucky... when they are challenged by certain... things they have to resist."

Does this same warlock who doesn't know that saving throws exist, nevertheless know that *two* *mind slivers* won't make someone more "unlucky", but a *mind sliver* and a *bane* together will make them
"worse at resisting... things"?  Or do I force them to insist that a fellow party member cast a *mind sliver* on a foe that already has one running, because their character can't know how the spell works?

You can keep pretending they don't know what a saving throw is, but player decisions will become increasingly divorced from any connection to the rules of the actual game - and it becomes burdensome [to make them talk in-character all the time](https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0297.html).

Ultimately, this is not about character knowledge – it is about how a player wants to *portray* character knowledge.  Find a style of description that is the most fun and fair for you and your players.  Find a style that works at your table, and don't worry too much about whether RAW a character knows something.

My preferred playstyle as a DM is that of co-operative storytelling – the game is the most fun for me when the players feel like I am challenging them to make it exciting for all of us, but not being adversarial because I am out to get them.  Within that context, they trust me not to meta-game, which means keeping my DM knowledge separate from NPC knowledge rather than using my personal knowledge of their characters to have NPC's "unfairly" target them.  That trust works toward maintaining the cooperative nature of the game.  At least once per session, I say something like, "Ok I forgot to turn the dynamic lighting barrier on – the wizard didn't actually 'walk through that wall', so please forget what you saw", or "Did I say the cleric targets you with a spell?  Your characters don't know that, I meant to say the robed woman attacks you with a spell."  I find that the more I can extend to them the trust that they give me, the more this particular playstyle is reinforced.