# When a character succeeds on a wisdom saving throw, are they aware they were targeted?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

Consider a spell that forces a wisdom saving throw on a target, which, in the event of a successful save, has no effect. Assume the target did not witness the casting of the spell.

- Does the target know that they were targeted, if they succeed on the save?
- Does the target know they were targeted, if they were immune to the effect, so they never even rolled a save?

**In addition, does it depend on which specific spell was cast?**
Let's consider the 3 following "categories" depending on what would happen in the case of a failed save:

1. The effects of the spell would be evident and the target would be aware that they were targeted (for example, "[Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)")
2. The target would not be aware they were targeted (for example, "[Modify memory](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/modify-memory)")
3. The target would not be aware, and the spell would not directly affect the target (for example, "[Scrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying)")

Comment: Howdy! Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] and you can also visit the [help] for even more about how we operate.

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate, which is totally fine since it helps others find Q&As that may be asked slightly differently. If you feel like this isn't a duplicate, please let us know what differentiates and we can always reopen!

Comment: Related: [Do reactions that trigger on saving throws give knowledge of saving throws that would otherwise be secret?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177906)